# How to switch UINavigationController on UIButton touch in IOS

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITabBar that has five different view controllers. Each view controller has its own navigation controller. I have a special view controller that only appears the first time the user enters the app. My problem is that I can't figure out a way to present the `normal view controller` when the user is done in the `welcome view controller`. I have gotten it to present the viewController, but it has the same `navigationController` as the `welcomeView`, not the `navigationController` that should show for that view. How would I fix this?

Here is how I am pushing it:

```
- (void)toFeed:(UIButton *)sender {

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"TermsAccepted"];

//    FeedViewController *feedViewController = [[FeedViewController alloc] init];
//    
//    [self.navigationController pushViewController:feedViewController animated:YES];

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing the rootviewcontroller of the navigation conrtoller.

[navController setViewControllers:newViewController animated:NO];

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

-(void)switchRootViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController{

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.window duration:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^(void) {
                    BOOL oldState = [UIView areAnimationsEnabled];
                    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
                    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
                    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:oldState];
                }
                completion:nil];

}
```

or simple push

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:<#(UIViewController *)#> animated:<#(BOOL)#>]
```